# Using one socket for send() and receive()?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winapi, udp

I have developed a udp application in which a single server is able to handle 'x' number of clients.
Inside my server, there is a primary thread keeps on receiving requests/data continuously from the clients and keeps saving the information of each client in a list.

As soon as a request comes from a new client(i.e. from a client that whose information is not saved in the list), a new thread is launched and a separate socket is created for serving that specific client.
In other words, for each client, there is a separate socket and a separate dedicated thread.

Now, the problem that I foresee is that since there is only one socket i.e. single line for communication, there are chances that if both Server and Client send data at the same time, there are chances of data collisions.

How shall I cater such a situation?
Waiting for response :(

[image]

Comment: "New connections"? UDP is connectionless. Also, sockets are fully duplex, and can handle simultaneous communication in both directions at the same time.

Comment: Does "being duplex" mean that socket is "ABLE" to both send and receive?
If yes, then I am not worried about socket's ability to receive and send.
My concern is that since there is one line between server and client and only one socket, what will happen if Server is sending the data at a socket and at the same time Client also sends some data to the Server.

Comment: That's what full duplex means. It works. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit about the number of sockets. On one hand you say there is only one socket, but otoh you say there is one socket per thread. Does the client data arrive via the original socket and the threads have a separate socket each to send out datagrams?

Comment: Or better yet, maybe you could show us some code?

Comment: There is one thread serving one specific Client having one separate socket. both sendto() and recv_from() is done using this single socket.

Comment: @Ayesha Hassan it's ok, the UDP stack knows how to handle this situation, don't worry.

Comment: I just noticed at least eight of your latest questions are about this same issue. I dont think I have the patience for this.

Comment: I wonder if you really want UDP sockets or if you should better use TCP sockets. At least the way you use the UDP sockets propose that what you want is TCP socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send a message over IP using TCP or IP the endpoints keep track of what's called a 5-tuple: source IP, destination IP, source port, destination port, and protocol (udp in this case).

If you're sending messages between *A* and *B* then messages from *A* will have a source IP of *A* and a destination of *B* from *B* will be the opposite. In this way It's possible to distinguish which direction the packet comes from and have packets cross in the network. That word, packet, is important.

A UDP messages isn't like a classic POTS phone conversation, where the two parties effectively have a wire between them, all for their use. UDP messages are more like letters in snail mail where each letter is called a packet.They can cross paths on the network and that's fine.

The 5-tuple is used at *A* or *B* by the network stack to figure out which user-space socket should receive the data, there's no confusion which destination certain data should go to. If you did have to wait your connection speed would be quite low and a complete round trip can take at least 10s of ms and a packet is nearly always less than 2k.